# Deploying plumber API via rsconnect (Handler not found)

Tags: r, plumber

I have a directory with a example API function (`testAPI.R`):

```
#* @get /mean
normalMean <- function(samples=10){
 library(plumber)
 data <- rnorm(samples)
 mean(data)
}
```

The `rsconnect::deployAPI()` function wants to point to a directory with a file named `plumber.R` that returns a `plumb` object. So I have the file `plumber.R` in the directory as:

```
library(plumber)
plumber::plumb("testAPI.R")
```

And then calling `rsconnect::deployAPI()` on the directory...

It deploys with no errors but seems to have not found the handler:
[screenshot of the swagger page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qa39g.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're still lacking good docs here, sorry. This will currently only work well when deploying to an RStudio Connect server; hopefully that's what you're using.

Internally, RStudio Connect uses the `plumber::plumb(dir=___)` function to invoke your API. You can see the docs there

> The directory containing the plumber.R file to parse as the plumber router definition. Alternatively, if an entrypoint.R file is found, it will take precedence and be responsible for returning a runnable Plumber router.

So you should either...

1. Rename your primary router to `plumber.R`, in which case RStudio Connect would find and invoke that file when it goes to execute your API. Or
2. Create an `entrypoint.R` file which returns your primary router. This approach allows you to do some extra customization on your router (or plumb a different file). It looks like the code snippet you provided would actually work if you specify it as the `entrypoint.R` file instead of the `plumber.R` file.

Comment: Great, I tried just renaming the file `entrypoint.R` and its working well now. I'm probably not proficient enough to help write a doc at this stage but hopefully after using it for a bit I could contribute something. Thanks