# rsconnect publishing API created by plumber

Tags: r, plumber, shinyapps

I have an API created by `plumber` in a file named `lltoClass.R` as follows:

```
#* @get/ ll.toClass
ll.toClass <- function ...
```

Also, according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47878677/deploying-plumber-api-via-rsconnect-handler-not-found?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) I have made a file named `plumber.R` containing:

```
library(plumber)
plumber::plumb("lltoClass.R")
```

according to [this](https://ifar-connect.hsl.harvard.edu/__docs__/user/publishing.html) I executed 
`rsconnect::deployAPI(api = "./project")` and it successfully deployed to my shinyapps.io account. but unfortunately only get this text on url of my api which automatically opened after completing the process of deploy:

> "An error has occurred unable to launch worker: API content cannot be
>   run on this installation of RStudio Connect. Contact your
>   administrator."

as I have tested my api on localhost I don't think its problem is due to my code. how can I fix this problem or how can I upload my API and use it publicly?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this comment](https://github.com/trestletech/plumber/issues/208#issuecomment-362438034) and [that issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rsconnect/issues/204) on github, plumber APIs are currently not supported on shinyapps.io.

Comment: Is there any other place to upload it freely? It is a test project and I will not use this API many times.

Comment: Ralf is correct; Plumber currently isn't supported on ShinyApps.io. See https://www.rplumber.io/docs/hosting.html for other options.

Comment: @mjoudy I do not know any free and easy service. With some effort, you could deploy your own using some free cloud server (e.g. https://cloud.google.com/free/)